# Facebook JS SDK Issue with Logout - Expected Suspicious Login detection

Tags: javascript, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

We have a kiosk/terminal style solution wherein we follow the following flow:

1. User identifies himself in our system.
2. User lands on his profile page on our system & clicks on add FB account.
3. User gives permissions.
4. User is redirected to our logout page.
5. User is given an option to like a page before logging out.

   1. In the case of this problem, the small iframe of the FB Like Social Plugin redirects to a Connection Error page
   2. Apparently, as pretty much expected, even the Logout link stops working.
6. In the cases where there is no error, the user logs out using the logout link on our logout page.
7. User is logged out of Facebook & redirected to his profile page on our system.
8. User logs out of our system.

The above repeats for multiple users present at the venue.

The overall flow used, that is relevant to the issue can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/d4952a6ba58c8aa961ff).

Comment: can you edit in the code please.

Comment: Are all the URLs in question https-enabled? That'd be my first wild guess.

Comment: @JimmySawczuk Yes. They are https enabled.

Answer (score 0):

refer to the new js sdk:

first glance, if the like button is breaking this may be due to your document settings, or a timing issue...  I would suggest loading the like button from within js sdk async and parse it with xfbml

```
<div id="likebutton"></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
function likebutton(){
var likeb=document.getElementById('likebutton');
likeb.innerHTML+='<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="<?=$fblike;?>" data-width="500" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>';
FB.XFBML.parse(likeb);
};
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
    appId  : 'AppID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });
likebutton();
      };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```